# Route between children without reload parent Angular +2

Tags: angular, routes

I have this route config

```
{
                path: 'Settings',
                component: SettingsComponent,
                canActivate: [SiteRouteGuard],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        redirectTo: 'General', pathMatch: 'full'

                    },
                    {
                        path: 'ChangePassword',
                        component: ChangePasswordComponent,
                        canActivate: [SiteRouteGuard]

                    },
                    {
                        path: 'Privacy',
                        component: PrivacySettingsComponent,
                        canActivate: [SiteRouteGuard]

                    },
                    {
                        path: 'Links',
                        component: LinksComponent,
                        canActivate: [SiteRouteGuard]

                    },
                    {
                        path: 'Profile',
                        component: ProfileInfoComponent,
                        canActivate: [SiteRouteGuard]

                    },
                    {
                        path: 'General',
                        component: GeneralSettingsComponent,
                        canActivate: [SiteRouteGuard]

                    },

                ],
            },
```

If I put function in `SettingsComponent` inside `ngOnInit()` for example `load()`. If I route between `ChangePassword` component and `Privacy` component every time the function `load()` has been called. How can I stop reloading the parent and just route between its children?

Comment: With a similar architecture I don't have this problem. There's something wrong on your implementation.

Comment: If you are requesting the child route by typing it into the address bar in your browser, it will always load the parent components. However if you use `routerLink`, it should only load the child route.